# How does finding nested aura components work?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, javascript-controller

In my team's code base, there's code of this structure:

```
function() {
    const first = component.find( 'level-one' );
      if ( !$A.util.isEmpty( first ) ) {
        const second = first.find( 'level-two' );
        //code not relevant to the question at hand
    }
}
```

Which is equivalent to something like this:

```
component.find('level-one').find('level-two');
```

This seems to work in the pre-existing code. But When I do this, I get the error

```
component.find(...).find is not a function
```

When I check for the value of `component.find('level-one')`, it looks like the correct component. It even has a `.get` function. But it doesn't seem to have a `.find` function.

Is there something I'm missing? Is it a recent update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not intended to be able to "reach in" to another component and pull out its children, so `find` should not be accessible from a chained component, as the component you're in does not "own" the child component.

Given:

```
<!-- component1 -->
<aura:component>
  <c:component2 aura:id="component2" />
</aura:component>

<!-- component2 -->
<aura:component>
  <c:component3 aura:id="component3" />
</aura:component>
```

You cannot do `component.find("component2").find("component3")` from within `component1`.

Conversely, if you have:

```
<!-- component1 -->
<aura:component>
  <c:component2 aura:id="component2">
    <c:component3 aura:id="component3" />
  </c:component2>
</aura:component>
```

Then you don't need to chain, as you can simply do:

```
component.find("component3");
```

This may have been "allowed" in the past, but if so, it was a bug. You can't access components' internal elements, as that violates the principles of encapsulation that components are supposed to provide.

Comment: That helps a lot, thanks. Question- do you have a source on that?

Comment: @Sullivan I'm pretty sure it's in the docs somewhere, but it's been so long, I'm not sure where to find it.